# Can I map Cassandra string and long columns to a java Map<String,Long>?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

I am working on a test process that has two aspects to it. As a result, I am wondering if I can reuse a POJO I have made to hold data from Redis, and have my Cassandra data stored in the same object.
(This project is using spring-data-cassandra and spring-data-redis. I have the ability to add other libraries as I need.)

The existing object:

```
public class RedisCounter {
private String key;
private Map<String, Long> data;

...getters, setters...
}
```

(Data in redis in this environment is stored with many results under the same key)

In Cassandra, though, we have three items: Key (string), Column1 (string), Value (long).
So I would like to be able to map the Column1 and Value items directly into the RedisCounter data map. But I'm not sure this is possible. In other tests of Cassandra data, I've successfully created an object similar to this:

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class CassandraCounter{

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "key", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private String key;

private String column1;
private Long value;

...getters and setters...    
}
```

I am not currently having any success deciphering the annotations like `@Column` but I'm sure I'm also missing something.

Basically, I already have an aspect of this test which is successfully querying and validating the data in Redis. I am just wondering if I have to remake a lot of similar functionality with a Cassandra counter, or if I could somehow map those items directly (something like `List<Counter> results = cassandraOperations.select(cql, Counter.class);` where cql is a normal String).

Should I be making a base class and implementing these two counter variants instead? Something else? Thank you!